# Adding hover tool tip to bokeh histogram

Tags: python, hover, tooltip, bokeh

I have created a histogram in **bokeh** using the following code:

```
TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,hover"

for column in valid_columns:
    output_file_name = str( file_name + column + ".html" )
    data_values = stats[ column ].tolist()

    output_file( output_file_name )
    histogram, edges = np.histogram( data_values, bins=50 )

    source = ColumnDataSource(
        data = dict( data_value = data_values ) )

    p1 = figure( title = column, background_fill="#E8DDCB", tools=TOOLS )
    p1.quad( top = histogram, bottom = 0, left = edges[ :-1 ], right = edges[ 1: ], 
             fill_color = "#036564", line_color = "#033649" ) 

    hover = p1.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
    hover.tooltips = [ ( "Value", "@data_value" ) ]

    show( p1 )
    print( "Saved Figure to ", output_file_name )
```

where valid columns are a list of all columns I want examined within a **pandas** dataframe. I am trying to add a hover tool tip which will display the number of items stored in each bin but I have not be able to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to not use a [ColumnDataSource](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource), you can replace `@data_value` with `@top` and it should work with minimal editing:

```
hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [('Value', '@top')])
p.add_tools(hover)
```

i.e. editing the example [`histogram.py`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/histogram.html) in this way also works:

```
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

def make_plot(title, hist, edges, x, pdf, cdf):
    p = figure(title=title, tools='', background_fill_color="#fafafa")
    p.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:],
       fill_color="navy", line_color="white", alpha=0.5)
    p.line(x, pdf, line_color="#ff8888", line_width=4, alpha=0.7, legend_label="PDF")
    p.line(x, cdf, line_color="orange", line_width=2, alpha=0.7, legend_label="CDF")

    p.y_range.start = 0
    p.legend.location = "center_right"
    p.legend.background_fill_color = "#fefefe"
    p.xaxis.axis_label = 'x'
    p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Pr(x)'
    p.grid.grid_line_color="white"
    hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [('Density', '@top')])
    p.add_tools(hover)
    return p
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a couple of things:

1. Have a `source` of the same length as your `histogram`, not your `data_values`. To be more concrete, I think you want your `source` to be:

   ```
   source = ColumnDataSource( data = dict( data_value = histogram ) )
   ```
2. Add the `source` to your `p1.quad` call, i.e.

   ```
   p1.quad( top = histogram, bottom = 0, left = edges[ :-1 ], right = edges[ 1: ], 
            fill_color = "#036564", line_color = "#033649", source = source )
   ```

Comment: Just a heads up, mixing named columns and auto-created columns (from literal data values) in a user-supplied source is going to be discouraged in the near future. (Because doing so modifies the user-supplied source, and this can be unexpected and unwanted) I would suggest putting the `top`, `left`, and `right` columns in the source as well.

Comment: @bigreddot How would you put `top`, `left` and `right` into the source? In the gallery for histograms (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/histogram.html) these parameters are still used as shown in NublicPablo's answer, or am I missing something?

Comment: How to load and use CDS is covered in the users guide: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html